# Recover deleted .wav files from Win 11

Tags: data-recovery, photorec

I've had a couple GB's worth of .wav files removed (with shift+delete) from my Win 11 system. It was last week, and the machine has been powered off since. I've tried multiple different recovery tools, from Recuva to R-Studio to GetDataBack to Stellar to Photorec, and I'm not getting any deleted .wav files recovered, even in simple test scenarios on a second laptop. Both machines are perfectly normal (bootable) Win 11 laptops.

For Photorec, which I believe to be my best shot, I made a bootable USB with SystemRescue and searched for .wav files on the whole drive, but the tool returns 0 files. This I find suspicious -- no .wav files at all? I find many default ones on my test laptop. Am I using Photorec wrong? It doesn't have many options. I've tried treating my drive as both NTFS and the other one (EXT*). In both cases, 0/10 header files are found before the further passes. Is this a problem?

Of course, I've been following their [software docs](https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk_doc/photorec.html).

Comment: Something like this perhaps?  ..........     https://recoverit.wondershare.net/ad/data-recovery.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwyLGjBhDKARIsAFRNgW86U44nvaup8j2oCjBUd1ZPjRmtILKfK8WlXBIDehcvAt8fS3uIoqYaAgbtEALw_wcB    .... If your main drive is SSD, you may not be able to reover.

Comment: Try [MiniTool Data Recovery Software Free](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/free-for-windows.html).

Comment: It is an SSD. Thanks for the recommendations

Comment: How big is the drive & how much room is left on it? Is it encrypted? Presumably it's an SSD? How much data have you written to it whilst trying to recover from it? …because right now mainly what you're doing is sawing off the branch you're sitting on. At least for Photorec you booted from an external, but what about the others?

Comment: It's got 1TB, with ample free space (>500GB). Unencrypted. I have left it powered off, other than booting to USB. I didn't think this would impact the target drive.

Comment: I don't think any software like above ones will help you much. Downloading/installing them will just cause more sectors to be overwritten by data. Your idea of liveUSB with e.g. photorec is what I'd do, although chances are likely low.

Comment: It is an SSD. Thanks for the recommendations     .....   Most likely (after Shift-Delete) the files are gone.

Comment: Ok. I've installed nothing to the target drive itself. Sounds like Shift+Delete + SSD = Bad news

Comment: Even if you don't install to the drive itself, there's a lot of file operations that will happen on the SSD, assuming it's the system disk. Cache, user data, prefetch, registry, etc.

Comment: SSD then virtually no chance: https://youtu.be/NyLQbxnPurc

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Or more specifically, the chance that you can recover from an SSD has to do with it having another fault (TRIM command dropped), which isn't likely to happen. If it is a properly functioning drive, the expectation is that it is unrecoverable.

Comment: Microsoft also have their own file recovery tool now - https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N26S50LN705

Comment: FWIW I'm *sure* you've had this thought a billion times already.  But if you haven't, give some thought to an automatic backup system, either locally or in the cloud.  And if you're already done this feel free to hate me.

Comment: *"Sounds like Shift+Delete + SSD = Bad news"* No, "not having backups" = Bad news. Backups will not only protect you against Shift+Delete, but also against failing hardware, ransomware, the cat jumping on the keyboard, etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Deleted files in general assuming Windows 10/11 + NTFS:

I will also assume we bypass the recycle bin. Upon deletion:

1. File's $MFT record is flagged 'not in use'. This is most important as the rest of the entry remains intact.
2. INDX is modified but more importantly the clusters that were allocated to the file are marked free in the $Bitmap.

[image]

A file system based undelete or file recovery tool can examine the $MFT and $Bitmap in a matter of seconds usually.

1 means that as long as the entry is not re-used we can retrieve information like the file name, the file's parent (folder) and the complete list of clusters that were allocated to the file (assuming all cluster 'runlists' fit one MFT record).

2 Means that clusters that were allocated to the file can be overwritten at any point. On a system drive we need to consider the OS is constantly writing to the drive. Also, software we download to recover files, software we install to recover files, potentially overwrite the very data we're trying to recover.

To recover an intact file we need 1 and 2. If we lose 2 then recovery is pointless. If we lose 1 only there's a chance we can 'carve' the file. In this case file system based recovery and undelete tools will not detect the deleted file (Journals aside).

PhotoRec is a 'carver': It scans the entire drive (although it offers an option to limit scanning to free space only) and looks for 'magic bytes'. For example, a JPEG start with byte sequence 0xFF,D8,FF and if we find such a sequence on a cluster boundary there's a fair chance we found the start of a JPEG file.

Since we have to scan the entire drive (or the entire free space) if we use a tool like PhotoRec we can see this is far from ideal. Add to that the tool due to it's very nature is bound to produce 'false positives' and does not recover file properties such as file names and we see a file system based undelete tool is the better choice.

**How long before a deleted file get overwritten?**

You don't know. While it is true that a scan for deleted files some times will detect files that were deleted months ago, it is also true that a file you deleted minutes ago is already beyond recovery.

**How do these tools estimate the status of deleted files?**

Many undelete type tools will tell you if they 'think' the file can be recovered. They give some percentage or will simply state for example 'good' or 'poor'.

By comparing the clusters that were allocated to the deleted file to the state of these clusters in the $Bitmap it can be determined if these clusters are 'free'. And if so, it is assumed the clusters that were allocated to the file have not yet been overwritten.

Another method that can be applied is seeing if the file extension matches the 'magic bytes'.

### Now assuming files are deleted from a SSD + Windows 10/11 + NTFS

Windows usually sends TRIM commands to the SSD immediately but this concerns the LBA sector addresses associated with the data clusters only. Treat this as rule of thumb to which exceptions are possible. Again usually SSD's 'un-map' 'trimmed' LBA addresses and from that point on return zeros if we read from the LBA addresses (RZAT).

Sometimes there ie some discussion as to whether TRIM commands are sent immediately due to the fact that Windows also runs scheduled (weekly) TRIM. But immediate and scheduled TRIM *both* happen.

The $MFT record itself is not affected by TRIM, it is simply flagged 'not-in-use'.

This means:

- PhotoRec will not be able to detect the files.
- A file system based recovery tool may be able to 'detect' the file, but the recovered file will be zero filled.

This video demonstrates the above: https://youtu.be/NyLQbxnPurc

**Some exceptions to the rule of thumb**

- Exception are files that are small enough to fit inside the MFT entry (small text files, .ico files and such), those can be recovered as long as the $MFT record is not re-used.
- I have seen the Windows file system drives refraining from sending TRIM commands in case of file system issues. After chkdsk trimming happened again.

Comment: Disappointing. But great answer, thank you

Comment: Ugh, *why* do windows CLI tools go for the aesthetics of 8-bit midnight commander?

Comment: @2e0byo still better-looking than all the *nix tooling that seems to be stuck in the 70's with progress bars consisting of equals signs interspersed with a handful of Unicode emoji, walls of text and otherwise unintelligible output. IMHO.

Comment: @2e0byo: What CLI tool are you referring to anyway?

Comment: @CodeCaster ;) but we've recently discovered the *spinning* ascii-art progress bar! JoepvanSteen whatever that screenshot is from. Anyhow my comment was pure noise sorry.  I learned something though: I didn't know windows issued TRIM immediately on delete.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is impossible but even if it wasn't, you would not want to recover them anyway because they would not be usable. WAV files store non-encoded raw waveform, and are therefore especially sensitive to all perturbations. Deletion marks the space occupied by files as free estate and the contents will degrade badly over time. Even if recovered, they would be at least moderately damaged and sound plain horrible, with a lot of random static noise all over the place.

Comment: Aren't uncompressed files actually *least* sensitive to pertubations? Small-scale errors have small-scale effects, unlike compressed files where it may break the whole file. There is also a lot of redundancy in the data, allowing for some automatic correction.

Comment: @IS4: You are correct that uncompressed files are less sensitive to corruption.  However "small-scale" corruption is what you expect from hardware on the verge of failure, not from "free space being reused", where the disk cache reads and writes at block granularity (and won't read a block marked "free" before making changes in RAM).  And there's no redundancy inherent in WAV format.  The particular data may be significantly oversampled, or it may make full use of the available bandwidth of the sampling rate.  We aren't told if these are recordings of human speech, music, or other data.